# fromEvent not getting keyboard events

Tags: angular

Why isn't this getting the keyboard type events? Its not printing anything to console. I'm copying code from this [page](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage)

```
  ngOnInit() {

    const searchElement = document.getElementById('search-input');

    const typeahead = fromEvent(searchElement, 'input').pipe(
      map((e: any) => e.target.value),
      tap(term => console.log('searching... ', term)),
      filter(text => text.length > 2),
      debounceTime(10),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => this.searchService.search(term))
    );

  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search-input">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not `subscribing` to it, that is the reason nothing is emitted. `Observables` are not emitted if not subscribed

Add the following code :

```
typeahead.subscribe(data => {
 // Handle the data from the API
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not `subscribed` the `observable`, you can get the it `emitted` only after adding the below code

```
typeahead.subscribe(item => {
  console.log('subscribe');
});
```

check the working [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9atdx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)